# System.TypeInitializationException on iText7 new PdfDocument()

Tags: c#, itext7

This was working code until a recent iText7 update. I am getting a System.TypeInitializationException creating an instance of PdfDocument. The inner-most exception is FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have verified that I have version 5.0.0 of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging package referenced and verified the files to exist.

This is the snippet of code that produces the error. D:\temp is a valid folder that I have security to access. The code is being run from a Windows Form application using .Net Framework 4.8. Thank you for any ideas.

`

```
public static void CreatePDF(InvoiceModel model, string outFilePath)
        {
            using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outFilePath))
            {

                PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
                Document document = new Document(pdf);
```

`
The contents of outFilePath is

```
        outFilePath "d:\\temp\\Statement-WTCC-20221117.pdf" string
```

Here is the full exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'iText.Commons.Actions.EventManager' threw an exception.
  Source=itext.kernel
  StackTrace:
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.Open(PdfVersion newPdfVersion)
   at LabBilling.Core.InvoicePrint.CreatePDF(InvoiceModel model, String outFilePath) in D:\users\bpowers\source\repos\Lab-Billing\LabBilling Library\BusinessLogic\InvoicePrint.cs:line 33
   at LabBilling.Core.ClientInvoices.GenerateStatement(String clientMnemonic, DateTime asOfDate) in D:\users\bpowers\source\repos\Lab-Billing\LabBilling Library\BusinessLogic\ClientInvoices.cs:line 108
   at LabBilling.Forms.ClientInvoiceForm.generateStatementButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\users\bpowers\source\repos\Lab-Billing\Lab Billing UI\Forms\ClientInvoiceForm.cs:line 413
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Inner Exception 1:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'iText.Commons.Actions.ProductEventHandler' threw an exception.

Inner Exception 2:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'iText.Commons.ITextLogManager' threw an exception.

Inner Exception 3:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Inner Exception 4:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: After troubleshooting for a period, due to a looming deadline I looked at PdfSharp and decided to use it instead. I was able to code the invoices relatively quickly, and it works like a charm. I am sure IText7 is a good product, so would like to see the resolution to this issue for future projects.

Comment: issue is still there in version 8.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I have rolled back from version iTtext 7.2.5 to 7.2.4 and it worked.